# suitable column Data-type for geojson data storage and processign in PostGis

Tags: postgis

I  have a MySQL table with 2 columns, id, a unique geometry id, and GeoJSON stored as a varchar, eg,

```
{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [116.4, 45.2, 11.1]}

{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-91.23046875,45.460130637921],[-79.8046875,49.837982453085],[-69.08203125,43.452918893555],[-88.2421875,32.694865977875],[-91.23046875,45.460130637921]]]}

{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.2963205,37.5359200],[-122.2975821,37.5370150]]}

{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-122.3035793,37.5391205],
[-122.3026703,37.5376882],[-122.3026739,37.5376868],[-122.3035843,37.5391212],[-122.3035326,37.5391600],[-122.3035298,37.5391576],[-122.3035793,37.5391205],[-122.3035793,37.5391205]]],[[[-122.3026703,37.5376882],[-122.3026703,37.5376882],[-122.3026703,37.5376882],[-122.3026703,37.5376882],[-122.3026703,37.5376882]]]]}
```

I wish to store this data in PostGIS, and then I will run queries to check if a given lat/lon is in any of the geometries stored in the DB or the distances to them, etc.

If I use the geometry datatype I will have to specify the type as point, polygon etc, but I want all types in one column.

Comment: Geometries in PostGIS can also be defined to be of a general type "geometry".

Comment: I have a vague recollection that key word  geometry/geography type and hstore type could be very useful for you.
i'm not sure if psotgis support json column queries (select from x where json.key like 'something' ) but i recall that hstore should be "easy" solution for it

Comment: What version of Postgres/Postgis. There is a native binary JSON type, JSONB, since 9.1, that allows for indexing of JSON. You still might be better splitting the JSON up and inserting as real geometry types. Could you clarify what type of queries you will be running.

Comment: yes the general type "geometry" helped me
for that I added 2 extensions
1) postgis
2) postgis_topology
Also with every geoJson object I was bound to add this key_value pairs
"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}

Comment: If you have mixed srid in table you can use  ST_SRID (http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html) to get correct srid for feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your geometry column as a GeometryCollection. Then you can add whatever geometry type you want in each row.

http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT

CREATE TABLE foo
(

...

...

geom geometry(GeometryCollection,4326)

)